# search a structure element in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

i am new to C++(also english).
i want to search {1,2,3} in the map and if it exists , print TRUE on screen
but i can not
my code comes below
can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#define PKT_UNIT_MAX_LEN  10000
using namespace std;

struct PKT_UNIT
{
int len;
unsigned int checksum;
unsigned char data[PKT_UNIT_MAX_LEN];


};

int main()
{
 map<int,PKT_UNIT> maharan;
 maharan.insert(pair<int,PKT_UNIT>(1,{1,2,3}));

 map<int,PKT_UNIT> ::iterator it;
 it=maharan.begin();

 for(it=maharan.begin(); it != maharan.end(); it++ )
 {

  if (maharan.find(it)!=maharan.end())
  {
   if (it->second.len==1 && it->second.checksum==2 && it->second.data==3)
   cout<<"TRUE"<<endl;

  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it->second.data` is an array. Did you mean `it->second.data[0] == 3` in the comparison?

Comment: overload an assignment operator for PKT_UNIT similar to 
inline bool operator ==(const PKT_UNIT &t,const PKT_UNIT &t2)

Comment: yes we can assume it->second.data[0]==3

Comment: Please expand on "I can not". What problem did you get?

Comment: as i said i am new in c++. and my code is with error

Answer (score 0):

You should overload the equality operator for `PKT_UNIT`. Then you should just use `std::map::find` to find what you are looking for.

```
bool operator==(const PKT_UNIT& lhs, const PKT_UNIT& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.len == rhs.len) &&
           (lhs.checksum == rhs.checksum) &&
           std::equal(lhs.data,lhs.data + PKT_UNIT_MAX_LEN,rhs.data);
}
```

The  you can do something like this:

```
PKT_UNIT goal {1,2,3};
for (const auto& e : maharan)
{
    if (e.second == goal)
    {
        std::cout << "TRUE\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, as it seems you don't need the key, maybe you want to use `std::set` and use a search algorithm, or `std::unordered_set`, in which case you wouldn't need a search algorithm at all.

Comment: `maharan`'s key is `int`, not `PKT_UNIT`

Answer (score 0):

`map::find` takes something comparable to the `key_type`, not the `mapped_type`, and certainly not an iterator. Searching for the value is not what `std::map` is designed to support. You can instead use the [generic searching algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
bool operator==(const PKT_UNIT& lhs, const PKT_UNIT& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.len == rhs.len) 
        && (lhs.checksum == rhs.checksum) 
        && std::equal(lhs.data, lhs.data + lhs.len, rhs.data);
}

int main()
{
    PKT_UNIT needle{1,2,3};
    std::map<int,PKT_UNIT> maharan;
    maharan.insert(pair<int,PKT_UNIT>(1,needle));

    auto it = std::find_if(maharan.begin(), maharan.end(), [&needle](auto & item){ return item.second == needle; });
    if (it != maharan.end())
    {
        std::cout << "TRUE";
    }

    return 0;
}
```